# Identify fretboard wood

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, fretboard

[image]

Hello  this fretboard is made of rosewood or ebony?

Comment: Ebony is darker than that - but that doesn't mean it's rosewood either.

Comment: Could it be macassar ebony

Comment: I does look like ebony, and rosewood is a protected spices these days.

Comment: What make and model guitar is it? The grain looks way too close for rosewood, but it’s not a very clear picture.

Comment: Its an esp ltd m-1001. On the esp’s website it says macassar ebony but on the seller’s website it says rosewood therefore i dont know which one is correct

Comment: Looks more like ebony, but it's impossible to say for sure from the photo.

Comment: Here’s a better picture        
https://imgur.com/gallery/bf1rdLg?s=wa

Comment: My guess is ebony.

Comment: If the manufacturer website says ebony it'll be ebony, but posting your question on The Gear Page forum might be a good bet.

Answer (score 1):

My dad is a [luthier](https://portland-guitar.myshopify.com/pages/jays-biography) of 13 years he says it is ebony. It is most likely Macassar Ebony if your in the United States as [Madagascar Ebony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illegal_logging_in_Madagascar) is not legal to import.

Answer (score 0):

Ebony.  Rosewood is more open grained and less dense.